# How to modifiy a specific element using Sabre_OTA_ProfileUpdateRQ

Tags: api, soap, sabre

I couldn't find in the Sabre's API documentation how to specify which element add in order to modify a field when more than one element of the same type is present on the same profile, for instance an email address.

I'm getting a "Can not distinguish EmailType element." error

Do I need to add any reference number or something like that?

```html
<Sabre_OTA_ProfileUpdateRQ Version="6.61.4" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sabre.com/eps/schemas \schemas\Sabre_OTA_ProfileUpdateRQ.xsd">
        <ProfileInfo>
            <PartialUpdates>
                <TPA_Identity UniqueID="000000000" ProfileTypeCode="TVL" ClientCode="TN" ClientContextCode="TMP" DomainID="XXXX"/>
               <Modify>
          <ModifySubtree child="/Profile/Traveler/Customer/Email">
          <MatchSubtree>
            <Traveler>
              <Email EmailAddress="asd@gmail.com"
              />
            </Traveler>
          </MatchSubtree>
          <NewSubtree>
            <Traveler>
              <Email EmailAddress="asd@hotmail.com"/>
            </Traveler>
          </NewSubtree>
           </ModifySubtree>
              </Modify>
            </PartialUpdates>
        </ProfileInfo>
    </Sabre_OTA_ProfileUpdateRQ>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Partial Updates feature in Sabre Profiles hasn't been implemented yet. Other than using the full update, which deletes the whole Profile and then updates it with what you send in the EPS_EXT_ProfileUpdateRQ call, one alternative you can use to achieve similar results is to review the section in the technical user guide regarding how to use the Ignore Subject Area functionality. You can update the Profile ignoring the other subject areas and send over the update for the email field only.